# How to stream data from the server using WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

My task is to simply make controller that gives me results immediately when they are ready (simple example below)

### Imagine:

I want to get the exact number of Strings (for example 1000 Strings that are somehow made for ***1 second***)
(actually I need to get result of func but to simplify the task just Strings)

So when I get some request in my controller I want it to give answers ***as soon as they are ready*** (without buffering results) in that way:

### What I want is:

1 second

"some string" -> (send response to my frontend)

1 second

"another one" -> (send response to my frontend)

1 second

"third one" -> (send response to my frontend)
....

### But what I get is:

1000 seconds

"some string"

.....

"thousand strings"

Here is my code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/3", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<String> get3() {
        System.out.println("get3 start");
        Flux<String> result = Flux.fromStream(IntStream.range(1, 10).mapToObj(i -> {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "flux data--" + i;
        }));
        System.out.println("get3 end");
        return result;

    }
```

Actually in my console I get

"get3 start" and "get3 end" immediately
but response only goes after all strings are ready

My actual service for this task is similar (but I merge 2 Flux here) and I get Flux which is formed by interval so I want it to give me results as soon as they appear

```
public Flux<AnswerCalculationDto> calculate(CalculationDto calculationDto){
        String checkMsg = checkCalculationDto(calculationDto);
        if(checkMsg.equals("Success")){//valid
            Long quantity = Long.parseLong(calculationDto.getQuantity());

            Flux<AnswerCalculationDto> firstFunc =  Flux.interval(interval)//func 1
                    .onBackpressureDrop()
                    .takeWhile((i)-> i < quantity)
                    .map((i)->new AnswerCalculationDto(i,1,translateToJava(calculationDto.getFunc1(),i)))
                    ;
            Flux<AnswerCalculationDto> secondFunc = Flux.interval(interval) //func 2
                    .onBackpressureDrop()
                    .takeUntil((i)-> i > quantity-2)
                    .map((i)->new AnswerCalculationDto(i,2,translateToJava(calculationDto.getFunc2(),i)) )
                    ;
            return Flux.merge(firstFunc,secondFunc);
        }
        else {//invalid data from client
            return Flux.just(new AnswerCalculationDto("",checkMsg));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I was looking for is Http Streaming, furthermore note that Safari as well as Postman and axios (js lib - I used it in my frontend part) doesn't support http streaming so you cant see your output to appear as soon as one of the results are ready (only all results in 1 response), try it in Chrome.

Also if you struggle with  **frontend part** as I did, try to search for SSE - server-sent-events, for example this:
https://turkogluc.com/server-sent-events-with-spring-boot-and-reactjs/

hope this will help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

There are several options to stream data from the server using WebFlux:

- **Server-sent events** pushing individual events (media type: `text/event-stream`)
- **Streaming events** separated by newlines (media type: `application/x-ndjson`)

Here is a complete example that exposes both `text/event-stream` & `application/x-ndjson` endpoints and returns data in `json` format.
If you need plain text content - use `text/event-stream`.

```
@RestController
public class StreamingController {

    @GetMapping(produces = TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    Flux<DataEntry> sse() {
        return stream();
    }

    @GetMapping(produces = APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE)
    Flux<DataEntry> ndjson() {
        return stream();
    }

    private Flux<DataEntry> stream() {
        return Flux.range(1, 1000)
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .map(i -> new DataEntry(i, Instant.now()));
    }

    @Value
    @Builder
    private static class DataEntry {
        long index;
        Instant timestamp;
    }
}
```

To test `text/event-stream` use:

`curl -v -H "Accept: text/event-stream" http://localhost:8080`

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: text/event-stream
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8
< 
data:{"index":1,"timestamp":"2022-04-08T14:41:06.513352Z"}

data:{"index":2,"timestamp":"2022-04-08T14:41:07.527817Z"}

data:{"index":3,"timestamp":"2022-04-08T14:41:08.541706Z"}

data:{"index":4,"timestamp":"2022-04-08T14:41:09.553329Z"}
```

To test `application/x-ndjson` use:

`curl -v -H "Accept: application/x-ndjson" http://localhost:8080`

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: application/x-ndjson
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/x-ndjson
< 
{"index":1,"timestamp":"2022-04-08T14:42:36.081269Z"}
{"index":2,"timestamp":"2022-04-08T14:42:37.094928Z"}
{"index":3,"timestamp":"2022-04-08T14:42:38.109378Z"}
{"index":4,"timestamp":"2022-04-08T14:42:39.121315Z"}
```

The above example will produce 1000 records with 1 seconds interval. You could also generate unbounded streams using something like

```
private Flux<DataEntry> stream() {
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .map(i -> new DataEntry(i, Instant.now()));
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, still get all records after 1000 seconds (
Has just tested it in Postman (changed to 10 records and only got 10 records after 10 seconds)

Comment: Modified example for streaming but I would recommend to spend some time learning reactive API.

Comment: thanks for your help, I got the problem, I was looking for http streaming and the issue was that Safari as well as Postman doesn't support async responses, so when I tested it in Chrome everything worked, thanks again for help, much appreciate!!!