# Spring WebClient is not emitting any data from request

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

This is the content type of the request
[image]

I use spring boot and this code to redirect the stream from the web server to the browser.

```
   public Flux<String> getDataStream(String configType, String configId, String user){
    Flux<String> response = null;
    Optional<String> url = getLogURL(configId);
    if(url.isPresent()){
      logger.info("#WebClient initiation");
      WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();
      response = webClient.get()
         .uri(url.get())
         .accept(MediaType.ALL)
         .retrieve()
         .bodyToFlux(String.class);
    }
    logger.info("#WebClient response");
    return response;
  }
```

After making the request, I can see `#WebClient initiation` and `#WebClient response` in a log file.

This is the client-side JavaScript code statement, that hits the above code `getDataStream()`

```
let eventSource = new EventSource(STREAM_URL);
```

But it doesn't get any response from the server. I couldn't figure out what I am missing. The URL that `getDataStream()`->`WebClient` hits, confirmed to produces output.

[image]

Comment: when using curl you need to disable buffering if you want to stream the result you do that with either `-N`or `--no-buffer`

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to stream data from the server using WebFlux:

- **Server-sent events** pushing individual events (media type: `text/event-stream`)
- **Streaming events** separated by newlines (media type: `application/x-ndjson`)

If you need plain text content - use `text/event-stream`. Check [WebFlux async responses from controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71788973/webflux-async-responses-from-controllers/71789245#71789245) for a complete example.

To see response results you need to log it as a part of the reactive flow. Also, there is no `null` in reactive and you need to return `Flux.empty()` instead.

```
@GetMapping(produces = TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<String> getDataStream(String configType, String configId, String user){
    Optional<String> url = getLogURL(configId);
    if (url.isEmpty()) {
        return Flux.empty();
    }
    
    log.info("#WebClient initiation");
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();
    return webClient.get()
            .uri(url.get())
            .accept(MediaType.ALL)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(String.class)
            .doOnSubscribe(s -> log.info("#WebClient request"))
            .doOnNext(rec -> log.info("#WebClient response record: {}", rec));
}
```

Comment: Don't see the method doOnSubscribe.

Comment: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#doOnSubscribe-java.util.function.Consumer-