# spring boot webflux query data in continuous flux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

having the following code that produces a continuous flux of random strings :

```
@RestController
public class WebFluxController {

private final Random random = new Random();
                  
@CrossOrigin         
@GetMapping(value = "/documents")         
public Flux getDocuments() {                          
        return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))     .map(x -> "document-" + 
 random.nextDouble());         
    }
}
```

...how can I replace the random with a query to the database that will return a field of the last record, something like :

```
@RestController
public class WebFluxController {

@Autowired
private ReactiveDocumentRepository reactiveDocumentRepository;

@CrossOrigin     @GetMapping(value = "/documents")     
public Flux getDocuments() {                  
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))     .map(x -> "document-" + 
 reactiveDocumentRepository.findLastDocument().map(d->d.getDescription);     
        }
    }
}
```

...where
reactiveDocumentRepository.findLastDocument() returns a mono containing last document inserted in the db?
In other words, I want that query to be ran continuously over the database and publish last inserted record all the time

Comment: is your repository actually a Spring Data repository?

Comment: is a org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reactive you need to build a flow using operators that will be evaluated when downstream (in your case webflux) subscribes to the flow. Result is not immediately available and you can't just concatenate it with a string. `reactiveDocumentRepository.findLastDocument()` is reactive and you need to use `flatMap` instead of `map`.

```
public Flux getDocuments() {        
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))    
            .flatMap(x -> 
                    reactiveDocumentRepository.findLastDocument()
                            .map(d -> "document-" + d.getDescription)
            );
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer  - can you give me a hint also on how to consume it :   I'm doing in client something like   :WebClient client = WebClient.create();
                        Flux<String>  resultFlux = client.get().uri("...")
                                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
                                .retrieve()
                                .bodyToFlux(String.class);
                        Mono.when(
                                resultFlux.collectList().doOnNext(System.out::println)
                        ).block();

Comment: ...but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: you don't need to block. What exactly is not working? The code is correct but your Flux will never complete. It means that you client will never get response back until you implement streaming, but this is different question https://stackoverflow.com/a/71789245/9068895

Comment: client was not getting response back , but you are right , I have to implement streaming .Thanks a lot for the hint !