# Flux error events are not reaching clients

Tags: spring-webflux

I am using Spring reactor to create an SSE api. I have tested using curl and browser as well. But I am not receiving the error events on the client side.

```html
public Flux<String> getStream() {
        Flux<String> flux = Flux.create(sink -> {
            addEvents(sink);
        }, FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.IGNORE);
        return flux;
    }
    
    
    private void addEvents(FluxSink<String> sink) {
        sink.next("Hello");
        sink.next("World");
        sink.error(new IllegalArgumentException("Test"));
    }
```

Hello and World is received on client side. But not the error event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stream data from the server using WebFlux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71788973/how-to-stream-data-from-the-server-using-webflux)