# Spring webflux not streaming instead gives response after the processing is complete

Tags: java, java-stream, spring-webflux, flux, reactivemongo

I am trying to stream the data line by line, obtained from reactive MongoDb using spring webflux, but its not streaming instead it gives the response at bulk once the processing is complete it gives the response with the complete data. Below is my code

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/ldm")
    public Flux<String> getAllLdm(){
        return employeeService.getAllLDM();
    }
```

Service

```
    public Flux<String> getAllLDM() {

        Flux<LDMongo> ldmFlux  = repo.findByLogLine1("string being searched");
        return ldmFlux.map((l) -> LDMMapper.mapToLogLine(l.getLogLine())).switchIfEmpty(Flux.empty());
    }
```

Repo

```
@Query("{ 'line' : { $regex: ?0, $options: 'i' } }")
    Flux<LDMongo> findByLine(String line);
```

What is it that I am missing in code

Comment: make sure you define the right content-type. For details check https://stackoverflow.com/a/71789245/9068895. also note that not all tools support streaming